# Trigger a function upon editing a text in pyqt5 textbox

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a textbox in my pyqt5 app, built with QTextEdit Class, and I need a function that immediately activates upon editing something in the textbox.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531578/make-an-action-when-the-qlineedit-text-is-changed-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

According to qt [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textChanged) you can use QTextedit.textChanged() signal for this purpose.

Try this, will copy everything you writes on upper QTextedit at real time..

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
import sys


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.text = QTextEdit()
        self.aux = QTextEdit()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.aux)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.text.textChanged.connect(self.onChange)

    def onChange(self):
        self.aux.setText(self.text.toPlainText())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```